# Determine "Backspace" button pressing

Tags: java, gwt

How to determine in GWT that user pressed <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button? I tried this, but it does not work

```
  @Override
  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
       char charCode= event.getCharCode();
       if(charCode == (char) KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE){
           //do someThing 
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `keypress` event is implemented in most browsers as only firing when a character would be produced (and that's how it's being standardized: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress ). Backspace obviously doesn't produce a character; you should use `keydown` or `keyup` to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about it from a completely different angle and just track the length of the String entered into a TextBox or whatever you want to grab the text from:

```
        // Global variable to save previous String data
        String stringEntered = "";

        // Our TextBox
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {

            if(stringEntered.length() > textBox.getValue().length()) {
                // At this point we know that a character has been deleted, 
                   so we can clear a list or reset something accordingly
                ...
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
   char charCode= event.getCharCode();
   if(charCode == (char) KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
       //do someThing 
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyUpEvent event) {
       char charCode= keyUpEvent.getNativeKeyCode();
       if(charCode == (char) KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE){
           //do someThing 
    }
```