# GWT - Autogrow TextArea

Tags: java, gwt

Here's my code where I tried to make a TextArea autogrow:

```
textArea.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                int lines = 0;
                final String s = textArea.getText();
                for(int i = 0; i != -1; i = s.indexOf("\n", i + 1)) {
                    lines++;
                }
                if (((int)event.getCharCode()) == 13) {  // User hit "Enter" key
                    lines++;
                }
                if(textArea.getVisibleLines() < lines) {
                    textArea.setVisibleLines(lines);
                }
            }
        });
```

However this does not work at all.

What I need is

- Grow the TextArea (height) as user put more text lines
- Shink the TextArea as user remove lines
- Should also be able to handle "CTRL + V" and paste text event

Given than the TextArea have been rendered with default height and width initially. 
Also if the text exceeds the width, a scroll left, right  bar should show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solutions:

- Grow the TextArea (height) as user put more text lines
- Shink the TextArea as user remove lines

  ```
  import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
  import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Overflow;
  import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeEvent;
  import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeHandler;
  import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
  import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
  import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
  import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
  import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;

  public void onModuleLoad() {
      final TextArea textArea=new TextArea();
      textArea.setStyleName("textboxStyle");
      textArea.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
      textArea.getElement().setAttribute("wrap","off");

      textArea.setVisibleLines(1);

      textArea.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

          @Override
          public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
              System.out.println("Value changed");
          }
      });

      textArea.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
              int lines = 0;
              final String s = textArea.getText();
              for (int i = 0; i != -1; i = s.indexOf("\n", i + 1)) {
                  lines++;
              }

              if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { // User hit "Enter"
                  // key
                  lines++;
              }
              textArea.setVisibleLines(lines);
          }
      });
      RootPanel.get().add(textArea);
  }
  ```
- Should also be able to handle "CTRL + V" and paste text event

  Yes you can handle it using `addChangeHandler` method

  ```
  textArea.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
          System.out.println("Value changed");
      }
  });
  ```
- if the text exceeds the width, a scroll left, right bar should show up.

  ```
  textArea.getElement().setAttribute("wrap","off");
  ```
- css applied

  ```
  .textboxStyle{
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
  ```
- screeenshots
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Its working perfectly. Please can you explain it more. What is not working. Please try it in a separate application. Find attached screenshot. I have updated my answer with imports and complete code. Please try it again.

Comment: **GWT version 2.5.0**

Comment: will not remove lines when using backspace, you must use KeyUp or KeyDownHandlers to detect these, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150208/determine-backspace-button-pressing

Answer (score 1):

I am using this approach to do something similar.

```
textArea.setVisibleLines(1);
textArea.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
    {
       textArea.setHeight("auto");
       textArea.setHeight(textArea.getElement().getScrollHeight() + "px");
    }
});
```

I am also applying these styles to fit my needs

```
.textArea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```